# "Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined" when using web3.personal remotely

Tags: web3js, json-rpc

When executing my script files from a machine that needs to connect to a remote geth node, I get an "**Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined**" when using **web3.personal.*** functions.

In particular I have started geth in one workstation with the following parameters:

```
> geth --datadir /home/user/eth/ --networkid 123 --rpc --rpcapi "personal,web3,eth,net,db" --rpccorsdomain "*" console 2>>geth.log
```

Initially I tested the scripts by executing them locally, using the following **HttpProvider**:

> Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545")

The scripts are executed as expected and all the **web3.personal.*** functions such as **web3.personal.listAccounts** and **web3.personal.unlockAccount()** work well.

However when I execute the exact same script from a remote workstation and thus replace localhost with the IP of the machine running geth I get the following error:

> Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined

To be noted that I can execute other functions remotely, such as **web3.version.api** and **web3.eth.contract(abiHEC)**, etc. 
So the problem seems to be the **web3.personal.***.

I am using **web3 version 0.20.6** and **geth 1.8.2.**

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Could it be that this is a security feature not allowing the use of personal functions remotely?

If so, do you have any recommendation on how I can invoke a smart contract function remotely? 
Thank you.

Comment: The keystore file must exist in the ethereum path. Are you sure those files exist on that remote system?

Comment: There is a keystore directory under the --datadir used in the example above, i.e. /home/eth/keystore/. There is a file for each account I have created.

Answer (score 1):

```
geth --datadir ./myDataDir  --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=2048  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --networkid 1114 console 2>> myEth.log
```

Put the IP of your machine in --rpcaddr and try it out.